# Is there any way to connect GCP to local IP ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

So my partner builds an API on top .NET and uses a local server to put the project. so to connect the API endpoint I need to create a VPN before I can access the API,

I've done connect from my PC to my partner local server, if in windows 7 
create a Workplace then filled Internet Address, destination Name, Username and Password.

So how can I do this from GCP till I can access my partner local server from GCP ?

Don't ask me why not just upload your partner api project to gcp.

thanks..

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you need and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to: just do it?

Just

1. Create a tunnel from a GCP Compute Instance (Virtual Machine with HTTP/HTTPS) to your partners local server on prefered port?
2. GCP offers VPN Products - https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview - maybe they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, there are a few solutions available. I’ll provide two solutions which may help you.

If you would like to set up an internal path from your GCP instance to your partner’s local server, maybe you should look into this following quickstart on [VPNs](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-route-based-vpns).

However if you’re looking to use an external path to connect your GCP instance to your partner’s local server, try exposing your partner’s server IP externally and configure a load balancer to it.